# javafx.fxml.LoadException on action event button to change scenes

Tags: java

I got a problem that I absolutely can't solve on my own because I have just started using JAVA FX. I get a nasty javafx.fxml.LoadException: , but I have done exactly like a guide, I can get my main to run, but when I try changing .fxml files via button_signup for a new scene, I get javafx.fxml.LoadException:.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/avsti/IdeaProjects/Assignment2/out/production/Assignment2/application/resources/register.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3331)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at application.Utils.changeScene(Utils.java:17)
    at application.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:22)
    at application.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:19)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Button.setOnAction(javafx.event.EventHandler)" because "this.button_signup" is null
    at application.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:19)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
    ... 55 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:348)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:210)
    at application.Utils.changeScene(Utils.java:23)
    at application.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:22)
    at application.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:19)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MyHealth.class.getResource("resources/login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("MyHealth");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button button_signup;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources) {

        button_signup.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Utils.changeScene(event, "resources/register.fxml", "Signup!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Utils.java

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Utils {

    public static void changeScene(ActionEvent event, String fxmlFile, String title) {
        Parent root = null;
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(Utils.class.getResource(fxmlFile));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

register.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="181.0" layoutY="103.0" text="Username:">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="183.0" layoutY="138.0" text="Password:">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="signup_username" layoutX="330.0" layoutY="103.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="signup_password" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="138.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="signup_firstname" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="175.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="signup_lastname" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="209.0" />
      <Label layoutX="178.0" layoutY="175.0" text="First Name:">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="180.0" layoutY="209.0" text="Last Name:">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="218.0" layoutY="338.0" text="Already a member?">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="button_register" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="255.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Register">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
      <Button fx:id="button_return" layoutX="327.0" layoutY="334.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" text="Login!" textFill="#0f19e1" underline="true">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
   </children>
   <cursor>
      <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
   </cursor>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post contents of file `login.fxml`.

Comment: I asked for contents of `login.fxml` and you posted contents of `register.fxml`. I see you have already accepted the answer so I advise that for your next question, try to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Button.setOnAction(javafx.event.EventHandler)" because "this.button_signup" is null
"

tells me that your button is null

try initializing it

```
    private Button button_signup = new button();
```

Comment: `button_signup` is annotated with `@FXML` hence it is probably supposed to be initialized by the JavaFX infrastructure in which case initializing it in the code would be wrong. Then again, the annotation may be the mistake and may need to be removed. That could be verified by viewing the contents of the appropriate FXML file. Unfortunately I could not find the FXML file contents in the original question. Did you?

Comment: No I didn't :/ I only read the error message and gave my two cents